# Getting Runtime error while using ShadowOf() API of Robolectric 4.1

Tags: robolectric

I am trying to use ShadowOf() API of Robolectric to verify if items in listview are displayed or not with changed data values when adapter's notifyDatasetChanged is called in development code.

**For this, I am trying to get ShadowListView and verify:**

```
ListView lv = myFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.myActualListView);
ShadowListView shadowListView = Shadows.shadowOf(lv);  // <-- fails at runtime
shadowListView.populateItems();

assertTrue(shadowOf(adapter).wasNotifyDataSetChangedCalled());      
assertTrue(lv.getChildCount() > 0);  

//more lines of code to access list item
```

However I keep getting errors for unrelated classes while running the test class.

**Earlier, was getting error for:**

> error: cannot access EuiccManager class file for
>   android.telephony.euicc.EuiccManager not found

**After including below line in build.gradle file:**

```
testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.6.1'
```

Getting error for SliceManager, which I have not used anywhere in my code -

> error: cannot access SliceManager class file for
>   android.app.slice.SliceManager not found

**My gradle file below:**

```
    //Robolectric
  testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.1'
   // testImplementation ('org.robolectric:shadows-supportv4:4.1')

   testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.6.1'


    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.8.9'
    testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito2:1.7.1'
    testImplementation 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.7.1'
```

Due to this error for missing class, I am not able to use Shadows.shadowOf() API. 
Is there any way I can unit test if listview displays modified values of data on screen with respect to notifydatasetchange() called in development code?

Comment: I am basically not able to use Shadows.shadowOf() API  which is the core of Robolectric framework. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Added 4.2 version of Robolectric, previous errors gone, now getting error for - error: cannot access WifiRttManager
class file for android.net.wifi.rtt.WifiRttManager not found

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade you compileSdkVersion to API 28.

It happens because new versions of robolectric make use of android.net.wifi.rtt.WifiRttManager in the shadowOf function, and this was introduced in API 28, so you must upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

Add 4.2 version of Robolectric.
All issues are solved in 4.2 version.

```
    *testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.2'*
```

**Note**: Android SDK version 28

Comment: Getting multiple issues while using 4.2 version    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical  for syntax -  mTestActivity = Robolectric.setupActivity(TestActivity.class); And    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x1120037 for syntax mTestActivity = (TestActivity) Robolectric.buildActivity(TestActivity.class).create().get(); while initialising activity. Hence, switching back to 4.1

Comment: This answer did not solve the issue faced. Not sure of +1 vote